# Listar datos con SQL Prepared Statements

Tags: php, sql

Necesito traer los datos de la Base de datos mediante un id. La clase Usuarios tiene la siguiente funcion:

```
public function getPerfil($id) {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id_usuario,nombre,apellido FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($idDB, $nombreDB, $apellidoDB);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;

    $stmt->close();
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
```

En la Base de datos tengo la columna: id, nombre y apellido y quiero mostrar su datos llamandolos desde otro archivo:

```
session_start();
require_once "clases/Usuarios.php";

$perfil = new Usuarios();
$datos = $perfil->getPerfil(1);

echo $datos->id;
echo $datos->nombre;
echo $datos->apellido;
```

Y me sale error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Hay alguna forma de poder mostrar los datos de la BD mediante estas consultas? Las puedo ver correctamente si las muestro dentro del While de la consulta, por ejemplo: `echo $nombreDB;` pero no las quiero tener ahi. Las quiero llamar de otro archivo para mostrarlo donde yo quiero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actualización**

Ya que en los comentarios has dicho que sólo te interesa mostrar el nombre, modifico el código optimizado:

```
public function getPerfil($id) {
    $stmt = $enlace->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param( "i", $id); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($datos);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    return $datos;
}
```

Y para obtener tu cadena puedes hacerlo por medio de una variable:

```
$id=1 //aquí el valor del id;
$nombre=getPerfil($id);
echo $nombre;
```

También puedes hacer el echo directamente:

```
echo getPerfil($id);
```

[Aquí](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_mysql_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMM3Z0a2U4UHI5WDA) tienes un ejemplo funcional del código que podrás probar pulsando donde dice: Execute.

***Nota final***
Se puede mejorar el método getPerfil() por ejemplo preguntando si la consulta no devuelve datos y enviando un mensaje diciendo que no se encontraron datos en caso de que la consulta no obtenga resultados.

---

He visto que en realidad no estás recibiendo un array desde tu función getPerfil(), sin embargo es lo ideal, sobre todo si quieres presentar tus datos desde otro lugar.

La función **getPerfil($id)** debería quedar más o menos así:

```
public function getPerfil($id) {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id_usuario,nombre,apellido FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* 
    *No tiene sentido usar todo el código comentado si usarás 
    * tus resultados en otro lugar, simplemente obtienes un array 
    * y lo devuelves con return...  
    */

/*    $stmt->bind_result($idDB, $nombreDB, $apellidoDB);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }*/
/* array asociativo */
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $datos = $result->fetch_array(); 
    return $datos;
    $stmt->close();
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
```

Entonces podrás leer desde la otra parte como te indico más abajo, con el foreach

Ahora sí... :)

Si te fijas bien, desde tu función **getPerfil($id)** recibes un arreglo, por tanto, para leer $datos tienes que iterar:

```
    if ($datos){        
        foreach($datos as $dato) {
                echo $dato["id"];  //¿id o id_usuario?
                echo $dato["nombre"];
                echo $dato["apellido"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "No se encontraron datos";
    }
```

Puedes comprobar lo que hay en $datos haciendo:

```
print_r($datos);
```

Comment: Al hacer el `print_r($datos);` me muestra los datos correctamente en array, pero con el foreach me muestran los errores: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in`... lo mismo con nombre y apellido.

Comment: En el echo $dato[''] has de poner como se llaman exactamente tus columnas en la tabla.

Comment: Si eso lo se, perdón, ese no es el error que me esta tirando, Me sale `Array ( [0] => 1 )` En el lugar del `print_r($datos);` nada mas, no me muestran los echos.

Comment: Revisa tu consulta, creo que no te está devolviendo los datos que esperas: id_usuario, nombre, apellidos.

Comment: He actualizado el código, ahora debe funcionar. En la función getPerfil sólo es necesario hacer la consulta y guardar los resultados en un array, mysql tiene posibilidades de devolver los resultados en arrays directamente con la función: fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); Devuelves ese array en el return y lees los resultados con el foreach... Saludos.

Comment: Mirá, no me funcionó como me lo pasaste, de todas formas lo pude solucionar agregando lo siguiente: `$result = $stmt->get_result();
  $datos = $result->fetch_array();
  return $datos;`
No se bien como funciona get_result, lo encontré por ahi y me funciona, no hace falta tener que hacerle un foreach para traer los datos ya que le paso un id. Solamente los pido de 1 fila. Saludos!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Yo suelo usar PDO en vez de mysqli ... Creo que el $result = $stmt->get_result(); sobra... si haces $datos = $stmt->fetch_array(); debería devolverte directamente el array... Cuestión de probar. Editaré la respuesta para que pueda servir a otros. Dime si sólo con el $datos = $stmt->fetch_array(); funciona bien.

Comment: Si le saco el result y lo dejo con el fetch_array solo me manda el siguiente error: `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in...`, con el get_result si me funciona. Y del otro lado, no hace falta usar el foreach, puedo mostrar los datos solamente poniendo `echo $datos['nombre'];`. Si le dejo el foreach me sale el mismo error que el de arriba: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in...`.

Comment: Mira, aquí tienes la información sobre el get_result: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php y aquí la de fecht_array: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php El error Illegal string offset 'id' significa que en realidad tu columna en la DB no se llama 'id', ¿se llama quizá 'id_usuario' ? en cada $dato[''] debes poner exactamente cómo se llaman las columnas que quieres mostrar.  El foreach se usa siempre cuando se reciben arrays, recomiendo que lo uses, por norma de programación, aunque en este caso muestre lo que quieres puede que no siempre sea así.

Comment: El nombre de la columna que puse aca id es diferente a mi codigo, lo tengo como id_usuario por eso me estoy mezclando jaja, no es ese el problema, lo probe recien con nombre solo y tampoco me funciona con el foreach. Me sale el mismo warning illegal string... Sin el foreach me muestra los datos correctamente. Ahi me pongo a investigar un poco como funciona el get_result :)

Comment: Ok. ¿Puedes pegar en un comentario lo que te sale cuando haces print_r($datos) ?

Comment: Sin el Foreach: `Array ( [0] => 1 [id_usuario] => 1 [1] => Maria [nombre] => Maria [2] => Paez [apellido] => Paez`
Dentro del Foreach, me muestra: `11MariaMariaPaezPaez`.

Comment: No termina de convencerme lo de get_result y fetch_array al mismo tiempo. Da la impresión que está duplicando los resultados. Mira un ejemplo funcional usando PDO, aunque usa una base de datos distinta, el concepto es el mismo: https://goo.gl/v1w9Gl Si le das a Execute verás debajo que te muestra en líneas diferentes el id, el apellido, la edad y el sexo... Creo que usando sólo fetch_array y luego leyendo usando el foreach debería funcionar, pero en vez de         foreach($datos as $dato) {
usas     foreach ($datos as $clave=>$valor){
    echo $valor.'<br>';
}

Comment: Lo saqué de aca: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178373/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-when-fetching-an-assoc-array]

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, con fetch_array me esta agragando los indices 0,1... Por eso se ve que se repite, si le saco el array y lo cambio por assoc, se puede ver bien el array: `Array ( [id_usuario] => 1 [nombre] => Maria [apellido] => Paez )`

Comment: Solo necesitas el array como lo muestras en tu ultimo comentario y luego lo puedes leer con un foreach pero de este tipo foreach ($datos as $clave=>$valor){ ... y haces echo de la variable $valor . La forma de mostrarlo es lo de menos, poner un <br> al final o lo que quieras.

Comment: Haciendo lo que me decis, esta bien, me muestran TODOS los datos, pero creo que no me expliqué bien, lo que yo queria era solamente traer 1 valor, por ejemplo el nombre solo. o el id, no todos. Por eso te decia que me parece que el foreach no entra en este caso. Con solamente usando `echo $datos['nombre'];` ya me funciona. De todas formas muchas gracias, seguramente lo voy a tener que utilizar en otro momento. :)

Comment: Bien. En ese caso tampoco hace falta incluir los campos id_usuario y apellido en tu SELECT. Para optimizar código y ganar en uso de recursos y en tiempo de ejecución puedes hacer un SELECT nombre... y recuperar el valor como una cadena sin necesidad de arrays. En ese caso no hace falta el fetch_array sino otra función de mysqli que devuelva valores simples.